# Incomplete type std::tuple_size<T> even though T is complete?

Tags: c++, c++20, stdtuple, incomplete-type

In the following code I try to get the tuple size of a custom type that derives from `std::tuple`. But the compiler complains that `std::tuple_size` is incomplete... which I can't really understand since `struct foo` is well defined at this point already. The same should naturally be the case for `type_descriptor<foo>`. Where is that error coming from?

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:12,endLineNumber:9,positionColumn:12,positionLineNumber:9,selectionStartColumn:12,selectionStartLineNumber:9,startColumn:12,startLineNumber:9),source:%27%23include+%3Cutility%3E%0A%23include+%3Ctuple%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%0A%0Astruct+foo%0A%7B%0A++++int+a_%3B%0A++++int+b_%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Astruct+type_descriptor%0A%7B%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate%3C%3E%0Astruct+type_descriptor%3Cfoo%3E%0A++++:+std::tuple%3Cint,+bool%3E%0A%7B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%7B%0A%0A++++printf(%22Size+of+tuple+%3D+%25zu%5Cn%22,+std::tuple_size_v%3Ctype_descriptor%3Cfoo%3E%3E)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:48.804757760371345,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g122,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-Wall+-Os+--std%3Dgnu%2B%2B20%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:41.3677130044843,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:58.632286995515706,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:51.19524223962866,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>
#include <cstdio>


struct foo
{
    int a_;
    int b_;
};

template <typename T>
struct type_descriptor
{};

template<>
struct type_descriptor<foo>
    : std::tuple<int, bool>
{
};

int main(){

    printf("Size of tuple = %zu\n", std::tuple_size_v<type_descriptor<foo>>);
}
```

This yields the following **error**:

```
<source>:89:27:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/utility.h:75:61: error: incomplete type 'std::tuple_size<type_declarator<foo> >' used in nested name specifier
   75 |     inline constexpr size_t tuple_size_v = tuple_size<_Tp>::value;
      |
```

Answer (score 5):

Inheritance doesn't mean equivalence. Your type, `type_descriptor<foo>` *inherits from* `std::tuple<int, bool>`, but it's not the *same* type. Thus template argument matching won't find it. If you wanted it to work, you'd need, e.g., a type *inside* `type_descriptor<foo>` that *is exactly* `std::tuple<int, bool>`:

```
template<>
struct type_descriptor<foo>
{
    using type = std::tuple<int, bool>;
};

int main(){

    printf("Size of tuple = %zu\n", std::tuple_size_v<type_descriptor<foo>::type>);
}
```